# Image id as digit causes W3C error

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, w3c-validation

I am using Drupal 7.9 and the images generate a numerical id automatically. It causes W3C validation error **value of attribute "id" invalid: "1" cannot start a name** because id attribute doesn't allow a digit as its name. The image tag is 
`<img id="1" class="media-image" alt="contact" src="path to image" typeof="foaf:Image">`. 
How can I get rid of this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**. As @SvartalF said, how can I prefix string to id in Drupal? I tried jQuery for that. But didn't help. This problem exists only with images uploaded via wyswyg CK editor

Comment: How're you outputting the images? are you using `echo render($content['your_field']);`

Comment: I am using wyswyg module with CK editor and upload images with media browser.

Comment: Closed as cross-site dupe: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18078/image-id-as-digit-cause-w3c-error

Answer (score 2):

HTML id value must begin with a letter, you can check it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).

So, you can prepend id with a some-prefix like a `image-`, or use HTML5 data-* attributes